# How to make SQL PIN login splash page, and make all other pages unusable unless entered PIN

Tags: php

BTW I am not a expert at PHP.

How I want this page to work is the index of this folder to show a form to enter a PIN, which I have did, and the action is set to a external PHP file.

I have managed to get the PIN to check against a mySQL query, and see if the PIN is correct.

I have been wondering how to make a random token in the database, only when the PIN is correct, print it to a table (the table is setup to have a incm. id number, and then the token column), then make the continue button, in the script,  go to the homepage with the (all too familiar) GET method: "?tk=[random but secure id from data base here]".

However, the problem here, is I want a simple way to do this for every page that I want to be private, using the same token (I'd assume checking the mySQL database for each page for that token), then I'd say 20 min. after deleteing the token id, to keep things clean.
 I'm sorry if there is any confusion, feel free to ask. I'm gonna figure that the PHP experts are going to puke at my PHP formatting skills. :)

PHP Pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/U3Lupvxc

Comment: You really should improve the visual clarity of your question: break it into paragraphs, use titles. I had a hard time just understanding what you are talking about. Also, avoid making multiple questions: creating a temporary token is one, preventing access on other pages is another.

Comment: Sorry about that, I made this post at 1:00am, but it did have breaks a such. But it didn't show in the actual post, either that or I missed something.

Comment: You can still edit it, though. Would you mind? It would definitely help. Thank you!

Comment: Still I don't understand. I missing clear question here =( Can you be more clarity?